# How can i reload a form with different arguments?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, reload

So i have created an application in Windows forms and C++, which prints out a piece of code, that you should write, what you think it prints out, and i have successfully done that, but now i need to make it so, that there are at least 2 pieces of code in each of the subject(arrays,functions uc).
this is what the form looks like to get the idea : http://scr.hu/0qz/fk7nn

So basically this form gets two variables when called - 'id' and 'step'

'id' - is used in a CASE operator to choose the subject.

'step' - is meant to be used to mark at which code you are, so if i call the argument as 2 instead of 1 it will load the form for "ARRAYS 2/2" not "ARRAYS 1/2".

BUT, i don't know how to "refresh" the form without loading it again.
I hope you understood what am i trying to achieve, and if you have any questions I'll be quick to answer!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but It's probably not a good idea to use C++/CLI (the version of C++ for .Net) when you're learning to work with .Net. Using C# would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be changed so that you aren't passing both values into the form.  If you are showing the form for related items that will all be like similar to a wizard, you could pass just the id for the category in and then use a collection to display the correct item depending on what step you are on.  This solution would then work for n number of items and wouldn't be limited to one or two items.